# Why the interpolation of resize in opencv is worse than that of PIL?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I tried `resize` functions with `openCV` and `PIL` respectively. And I found that the performance in `PIL` is way better. But according to the instruction, the method of interpolation is similar (e.g. bicubic).

Could someone provide any insight?

My complete code is below. I just want to resize the original image and padding it by pasting (for YOLO input).

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def letterbox_image_np(image, size):
    iw, ih = image.shape[1], image.shape[0]
    w, h = size
    scale = min(w / iw, h / ih)
    nw = int(iw * scale)
    nh = int(ih * scale)

    # resize image according to (416,416) & orig size
    image = cv.resize(imgNP, dsize=(nw, nh), interpolation=cv.INTER_CUBIC)
    # plt.imshow(image), plt.show()
    new_image = 128 * np.ones((h, w, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    # plt.imshow(new_image), plt.show()
    n = np.array(new_image)
    offset_h = (h - nh) // 2
    offset_w = (w - nw) // 2
    new_image[offset_h:offset_h + nh, offset_w:offset_w + nw] = image
    return new_image


def letterbox_image_pil(image, size):
    iw, ih = image.size  # as "Image" object
    w, h = size
    scale = min(w / iw, h / ih)
    nw = int(iw * scale)
    nh = int(ih * scale)

    # resize image according to (416,416) & orig size
    image = image.resize((nw, nh), Image.BICUBIC)
    new_image = Image.new('RGB', size, (128, 128, 128))
    # plt.imshow(new_image), plt.show()
    new_image.paste(image, ((w - nw) // 2, (h - nh) // 2))
    return new_image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # np_frame
    imgNP = cv.imread(r"C:\ProgamData\global_dataset\img_vid\down.jpg")
    # pil_frame
    imgPIL = cv.cvtColor(imgNP, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    imgPIL = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(imgPIL))

    size = (416, 416)
    # methodNP
    newImg1 = letterbox_image_np(imgNP, size)
    newImg1 = cv.cvtColor(newImg1, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    # methodPIL
    newImg2 = letterbox_image_pil(imgPIL, size)

    plt.imshow(newImg1), plt.show()
    plt.imshow(newImg2), plt.show()
    pass
```

### Example by by openCV

[image]]

### Example by by PIL

[image]]

Comment: Maybe add images demonstrating the degradation

Comment: I have, see the link "by openCV" and "by PIL". You could observe there's visible difference.

Comment: Maybe this [issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/17720) is related? If you are installing OpenCV with `pip install opencv-python`, I don't know if IPP is enabled or not. This is important since IPP contains optimized functions and in this particular case of bicubic interpolation, IPP and regular OpenCV code differ for the bicubic implementation.

Comment: In general, you should not expect bit-exact results with different algorithm implementations, especially with OpenCV.

Comment: @Catree Thank you for your opinion. Never thought of that :)